# Representation and alignment requirements of enum types

Tags: c, language-lawyer

[6.2.5p28](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#) mentions that

> ... All pointers to structure types shall have the same
>   representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers
>   to union types shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the
>   same representation or alignment requirements.

I believe it is this paragraph that allows code such as:

```
TAG x;

void take(TAG x* X) { (void)X; }

int main() 
{
  TAG x *xp = 0;
  take(xp);
}
```

to compile when `TAG` is defined as a macro expanding to either the `struct` or `union` keyword.
However, it also [compiles (tcc, gcc, clang) when `TAG` is defined as a macro expanding to the `enum` keyword](https://ideone.com/fICYcM).

Given the above, is the code with `enum` substituted for `TAG` conformant C? Why or why not?

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: Please update your question with actual compiling code. What exactly is `TAG` when you use an `enum` type? Is `TAG` a typedef? A macro?

Comment: @Stargateur It does: https://ideone.com/fICYcM

Comment: @PSkocik `#define TAG enum` was not in the OP

Comment: I don't get what is so surprising.

Comment: @Swordfish What's surprising is that if different pointers to different enum types are allowed to have different representations, then how can the compiler know what representation to pick for the `enum x` incomplete type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code from the link you gave in your comment:

```
#define TAG enum
TAG x;

void take(TAG x* X) { (void)X; }

int main() {
  TAG x *xp = 0;
  take(xp);
};
```

(The name "TAG" is misleading. A tag is an identifier; for example in `enum foo {a, b, c}`, the *tag* is `foo`.)

This is invalid.  When I compile with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`, I get:

```
c.c:2:5: error: ISO C forbids forward references to 'enum' types [-Wpedantic]
 TAG x;
     ^
c.c:4:15: error: ISO C forbids forward references to 'enum' types [-Wpedantic]
 void take(TAG x* X) { (void)X; }
               ^
c.c: In function 'main':
c.c:7:7: error: ISO C forbids forward references to 'enum' types [-Wpedantic]
   TAG x *xp = 0;
       ^
c.c: At top level:
c.c:9:2: error: ISO C does not allow extra ';' outside of a function [-Wpedantic]
 };
  ^
```

Since forward references to `struct` types are permitted, all pointer to structs have to have the same representation, since the compiler may not have seen the full struct definition when it sees a pointer type.

The same is true for `union` types. The same is *not* true for `enum` types, and it's possible for pointers to two different `enum` types to have different implementations.  Since forward references to `enum` types are not permitted, this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question, like to many others, lies in **running the compiler with warnings enabled**.

```
$ gcc example.c -Wall -pedantic
example.c:3:5: warning: ISO C forbids forward references to ‘enum’ types [-Wpedantic]
 TAG x;
     ^
example.c:5:15: warning: ISO C forbids forward references to ‘enum’ types [-Wpedantic]
 void take(TAG x* X) { (void)X; }
               ^
example.c: In function ‘main’:
example.c:9:7: warning: ISO C forbids forward references to ‘enum’ types [-Wpedantic]
   TAG x *xp = 0;
       ^
example.c: At top level:
example.c:11:2: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-Wpedantic]
 };
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried `-Wall -Wextra`.  Didn't realize I needed `-pedantic`.

Comment: `gcc` at least allows you to work with incomplete enums and pointers to them like this even if it isn't to standard: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Incomplete-Enums.html

Comment: @PSkocik Always use -pedantic (or -pedantic-errors).